# Getting the percentage of animation completed on view layer

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I'm doing animation on view's `layer` as a `progress bar`. I'm able to pause and resume the layer animation but unable to get the percentage of animation completed on pausing.

**Code for animating The width of view**

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.progressView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.width - 40
 }, completion: nil)
```

**For pausing animation**

```
func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}
```

**Animation code to resume**

```
func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1.0
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime

    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

Comment: What is driving the animation? Can you show that code

Comment: @agibson007 updated the view animation

Comment: I have the answer but until it is not on hold I cannot add the answer. But the current answer is not right

Comment: @agibson007 I don't know how to get it out from on Hold, can you please post it in comments

Comment: @skkrish It will be open soon. It was closed due to lack of the information in your question. So next time ask the question with proper information and with code what have you tried and what is issue in it.

Comment: @TheTiger Sure will do that.

Comment: Yo I left you an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is checking the **presentationLayer** of the layer that is being animated.  This is the animation model that you are seeing and why in the comments you stated that the width never changed.  It's because as soon as the animation is added the model layer value and frame are updated and all you are seeing is the presentationLayer kind of like a movie. The reason I needed to know what type of animation you were applying was so I would know what attribute of the presentation layer I was trying to get. Otherwise you all were on the right track in the comments about checking the bounds.width to figure out the progress of the animation Give this a shot.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var fakeProgress = UIView()
    var progressLabel = UILabel()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let progressContainer = UIView(frame:  CGRect(x: 20, y:50, width: self.view.bounds.width - 40, height: 40))
        progressContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        fakeProgress = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 40))
        fakeProgress.backgroundColor = .green
        self.view.addSubview(progressContainer)
        progressContainer.addSubview(fakeProgress)

        progressLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 40)
        progressLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progressContainer.addSubview(progressLabel)
        progressLabel.text = "0%"
        progressLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        progressLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressContainer.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: self.view.bounds.height - 60, width: self.view.bounds.width - 40, height: 40))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleAnimation), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("press for something", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.fakeProgress.frame.size.width = progressContainer.bounds.width
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            self.progressLabel.text = "\(100.0)%"
            self.progressLabel.isHidden = false
        })

        pauseLayer(layer: fakeProgress.layer)
    }

    @objc func toggleAnimation(){

        if let presentation = fakeProgress.layer.presentation(){
            let width = presentation.bounds.width
            let progress = (width/(self.view.bounds.width - 40)) * 100
            print("the progress is \(progress)")
            progressLabel.text = "\((ceil(progress * 100))/100)%"
        }else{
             let progress = (fakeProgress.frame.width/(self.view.bounds.width - 40)) * 100
            if progress == 100{
                print("finished")
                progressLabel.text = "\(100)%"
            }else{
                print("not started")
                progressLabel.text = "\(0)%"
            }
        }

        if fakeProgress.layer.speed == 0{
            resumeLayer(layer: fakeProgress.layer)
        }else{
            pauseLayer(layer: fakeProgress.layer)
        }

    }


    func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        progressLabel.isHidden = false
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        layer.speed = 0.0
        layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }

    func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        progressLabel.isHidden = true
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.timeOffset
        layer.speed = 1.0
        layer.timeOffset = 0.0
        layer.beginTime = 0.0
        let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime

        layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can be done manually, use the below code to get the start time of animation, and when animation stops call the function that gets you the time passed in seconds then you can divide the time variable in the code below by the total time of the animation then multiply it by 100 to get your percentage :)

```
  var startTime: Double = 0
  var time: Double = 0

  /* 
  When the animation starts, record the time and start a timer using the code below
  */
  startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

  //When the animation stops, invalidate the timer and do your percentage equation i described above:


  func timeDifference(timer: Timer) {

    //Total time in seconds
    time = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime

    //The rest of your code goes here

  }
```

Otherwise you can just create a variable that has the desirable width and another variable that holds the original width when you stop the animation the equation will be :

```
fabs(current width - original width) * 100 /desired width
```

Comment: this would be a nice workaround, but is there any way to get the percentage or the layer filled with from layer itself?

Comment: Would you put the animation code in your question ?

Comment: i can't tell what are you doing with the animation, i mean if you are rotating you can get the rotation degree and divide it by the initial rotation degree, etc ... but i can't just give you a direct answer for this case :(

Comment: I want to find the percentage of animation completed on every play and pause of layer animation, your solution works for only on the first pause.

Comment: I'm animating the view width for the duration of 3 seconds

Comment: i've updated the answer, please update the question to ask about animating width

Comment: and the first answer is okay, you just need to use it right, i am afraid you are resetting the start time on resuming and that is not right

Comment: but the current width of both view and layer remains same all the time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169345/discussion-between-skkrish-and-alsh-compiler).